# How to test my node/express app is making an API call (through axios)

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js, chai

When a user visits the homepage of my app, my express backend makes a RESTful http request to an external API, that returns a JSON.

I want to test that my app is making that API call (without actually making it). I'm currently testing in Mocha with Chai, and have been using Sinon and Supertest.

```
describe('Server path /', () => {
  describe('GET', () => {
    it('makes a call to API', async () => {
      // request is through Supertest, which makes the http request
      const response = await request(app)
        .get('/')

      // not sure how to test expect axios to have made an http request to the external API
    });
  });
});
```

I don't care about the response that the server gives, I just want to check that my app is making the call with the correct path and headers (with api keys etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done in the past for this scenario is I stubbed the server call using Sinon. Let's say you have a method for your server call

```
// server.js
export function getDataFromServer() {
  // call server and return promise
}
```

in the test file

```
const sinon = require('Sinon');
const server = require('server.js'); // your server call file

describe('Server path /', () => {  
  before(() => { 
    const fakeResponse = [];
    sinon.stub(server, 'getDataFromServer').resolves(fakeResponse); // I assume your server call is promise func
  });

  after(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  describe('GET', () => {
    it('makes a call to API', async () => {
      // request is through Supertest, which makes the http request
      const response = await request(app)
        .get('/')
      ...   
    });
  });
});
```

Hope it can give you insights.

Comment: You sir, are a legend. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to check the code returned from the response of the API. But basicaly to check if the code performs a API call, you have to do it.